# How to obtain value of JSON array as a result of get Request?

Tags: angular, spring-boot

How to obtain the value of JSON array as a result of getting Request?

```js
   @Component({
     selector: 'app-navbar',
     templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
      })
     export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {

    countries = ["Ukraine", "RSA"];
    data: Array<Country> = new Array();

      constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {

    this.http.get<Array<Country>>('http://localhost:8080/countries/db')
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.data = data;
      });

    console.log(this.data);
  }

}
```

JSON

```
[
  {
    "country": "Vatican-City"
  },
  {
     "country": "Zambia"
 },
 {
        "country": "Zimbabwe"
 }
]
```

I want to store the value of JSON as a string array in the data variable with Angular

Comment: really confused what you're asking. Do you want JSON object as a string? or something else?

Comment: Put the console inside the subscribe..

Comment: Actually i wanted the value of this json to be put in javascript object.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure If I have understood:

```
this.http.get<Array<Country>>('http://localhost:8080/countries/db')
      .subscribe(data => {
        const countries = data;
        const countriesLis: Array<string> = new Array<string>()
        for( let country of countries) {
           countriesList.push(country);
         }
        this.data = countriesList;
      });
```

Comment: This is correct, thanks Fed it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Try stringify():

```
const data= { name: "John", age: 30, city: "New York" };
this.data = JSON.stringify(data);
```

Comment: I tried that earlier it's not working, typescript gives a compiler error.